# MySQL SELECT with double quotes giving trouble printing in php

Tags: php, mysql, printing, double-quotes

If anyone has any ideas on how to help me out with this, when I run it usually just creates a never ending table.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'blah', 'blah') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('blah') or die('Could not select database');

extract($_GET);

error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );

$query = "SELECT `city`.`month`,`city`.`cost`, `comcast`.`cost`, `electric`.`cost`, `city`.`cost` + `comcast`.`cost` + `electric`.`cost` AS \"Total\" FROM `city`, `comcast`, `electric`";



    echo "<table border = '1'>

          <tr>

          <th>Date of Bills</th>

          <th>City Bills</th>

          <th>Comcast Bills</th>

          <th>Electric Bills</th>

          <th>Total Bills</th>

          </tr>";



$dave= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dave,mysql_ASSOC)) {

        echo "<tr>";

        echo "<td>" . $row[`city`.`month`] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row[`city`.`cost`] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row[`comcast`.`cost`] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row[`electric`.`cost`] . "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . $row[`\"Total\"`] . "</td>";

        echo "</tr>";





    }







//SELECT `city`.`month`, `city`.`cost`+ `comcast`.`cost`+ `electric`.`cost` AS "Total" FROM `city`, `comcast`, `electric`

// Free resultset

mysql_free_result($result);



// Closing connection

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: The reason you get a "never ending table" is probably because you are selecting all data from 3 tables without specifying a JOIN.  If your 3 tables each have 500 rows, then you're asking MySQL to return 500x500x500 = 125,000,000 rows.  Obviously you need to optimize that query!

Answer (score 0):

replace **`** with **'** when displaying data:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dave,mysql_assoc)) {

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['month'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['costCity'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['costComcast'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['costElectric'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['Total'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

and change your query to:

```
$query = "SELECT `city`.`month`,`city`.`cost` as costCity, 
                 `comcast`.`cost` as costComcast, 
                 `electric`.`cost` as costElectric, 
                 `city`.`cost` + `comcast`.`cost` + `electric`.`cost` AS \"Total\" 
                  FROM `city`, `comcast`, `electric`";
```

Also I would look into **JOINS** and you are missing closing table tag `</table>`

Since you are selecting all data from 3 tables without using joins it multiples so if
your tables contain 2 rows in each you get result `2*2*2 = 8`.

**NOTE:** do not use `mysql_*` functions. Try using prepared statements **PDO** or **MySQLi_***

Answer (score -1):

You should not be using backticks ` with `echo`. Use single quotes `'` instead.